# Angular FormGroup valueChanges converts properties to arrays

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm watching for changes on a fromGroup, however, it would seem that for empty / null properties in the formGroup, it converts these to empty arrays.

My formGroup instantiation looks like this:

```
  static create(validators?: ValidatorFn[]): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      estimatedSpend: new FormControl(0),
      currency: new FormControl(0),
      department: new FormControl('')
    }, validators);
  }
```

Nothing fancy, just added default values in.

When I look in Chrome DevTools, the value of the formGroup is correct:

[image]

However, when the valueChanges(...) kicks in, the values are converted to empty arrays?

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here, as this behavior is not as expected. Should I perhaps go through a FormBuilder rather?

**Update**

```
  instantiateFormGroup(group: any): void {
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup(group);
  }
```

This method is defined in a base component, as i have numerous components where this step gets repeated.

In each component which extends my base, I do something like:

```
  constructor(cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    super(cdr);

    this.instantiateFormGroup({
      clientQuestions: ClientQuestionsDTOFormGroup.create()
    });
  }
```

I do this in the constructor, as I override the default router-outlet's activate method to do specific things (completely irrelevant).

The `.create()` method:

```
export class ClientQuestionsDTOFormGroup {

  static create(validators?: ValidatorFn[]): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      estimatedSpend: new FormControl(0),
      currency: new FormControl(0),
      department: new FormControl('')
    }, validators);
  }
}
```

Comment: this.formGroup = new formGroup(group); , I can barely see this. Is it possible to get more code to see where you bind you formgroup?I do not know what method this is for, but should you not be doing this.formGroup = create(validator) ?

Comment: I supouse you want do do return this.formGroup.get(name).valueChanges.susbcribe(...). And remember call to function subscribeTochanges always after creaste the form

Comment: @Eliseo, yes, correct. I return the valueChanges as an observable which bubbles up to each component that implements the base component. I just want to understand why I'm seeing arrays instead of the default value i'm passing through during formGroup.create()

Comment: @JadedEric, you has write "map" (I think that this is because you get an array) -it will be more easy if we could see your function subscribeToChanges-

Answer (score 0):

It would appear a developer in the team committed code that iterates the keys of the original array, and replaces the value with that of an array, and added this piece of code as an override for FormGroup objects.

Comment: We all predicted it)

Comment: why code reviews should be conducted. will address this with the team's lead. thanks for the help.